# How to generate a unique id based on different id category?

Tags: mysql

I have a table as shown below

```
| id         | name        | doc_no       |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|
| 1          | abc         |     D11710001
| 2          | efg         |     D21710001
| 3          | hij         |     D31710001
| 4          | klm         |     D41710001
| 5          | nop         |     D51710001
| 1          | qrs         |     D11710002
```

I want to generate an unique id based on the id given. For example, when i have item to be stored in this table, it will generate an unique id based on the id of the table.

Note: The id in this table is a foreign key. The doc no can be modified by user into their own format manually.

The id format - D 'id' 'year' 'month' 0001(auto increment)

How can i write the sql to generate unique id during storing data?

Comment: You wouldn't normally store derived data

Comment: How do you want to get year and a month? Should it be from current date or from some other date?

Comment: You can use a Trigger with a `BEFORE CREATE` to construct your id and add it to the row.

Comment: It looks like you have two auto increment IDs are some sort in there.  Do you really need this?  I recommend just generating your custom ID when you actually query.  No need to duplicate data and make your updates very complicated unnecessarily.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn i get it from current date.

Comment: @FoxCy I am using phpmyadmin, and not sure how to write a trigger for this. Prefer to do it manually because user may edit their doc_no in their own format.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Forgot to mention the id is foreign key in this case.

Comment: So there's no PRIMARY KEY. Terrific

Comment: Just an example

Answer (score 1):

Continuing with the comment by @strawberry I might recommend *not* storing the ID in your database.  Besides the fact that accessing the auto increment ID at the same time you are inserting the record might be tricky, storing this generated ID would be duplicating the information already stored elsewhere in your table.  Instead of storing your ID, just generate it when you query, e.g.

```
SELECT
    id, name, doc_no,
    CONCAT('D', id, STR_TO_DATE(date, '%Y-%m'), auto_id) AS unique_id
FROM yourTable;
```

This assumes that you would be storing the insertion date of each record in a date column called `date`.  It also assumes that your table has an auto increment column called `auto_id`.  Note that having the date of insertion stored may be useful to you in other ways, e.g. if you want to search for data in your table based on date or time.

Answer (score 0):

You could create Trigger and update the column or you can write the update state just after your `INSERT`

```
insert into <YOUR_TABLE>(NAME,DOC_NO) values('hello','dummy');

update <YOUR_TABLE> set DOC_NO=CONCAT('D',
                            CAST(YEAR(NOW()) AS CHAR(4)),
                            CAST(MONTH(NOW()) AS CHAR(4)),
                            LAST_INSERT_ID()) 
WHERE id=LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Please note, as above SQL may cause race condition, when simultaneously server get multiple requests.

@Tim Biegeleisen has good point though, as it is better to construct the id when you are `SELECT`ing the data.

Comment: I don't think it is suitable to use trigger in my case due to user will modify the doc no in their own format. The doc no will be only generated automatically when user do not input the item code field.

Comment: @Zidance It is upto your application design. I'm just telling you the options.

Comment: @Zidance did you get your solution ?

Comment: No, i am doing something like select the doc_no which belong to that id if exist then increment else the doc no will start from 0001

Comment: @Zidance You need to post what you did.